# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java test step definition class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, compiler-errors

I work in  test project using JUnit I try to run my test it works  and when i re-run it doesn't work i have his problem , i don't understand the issue

I reed some answers about this to put ry and catch in the static method i do it but also doesn't work

Any idea or another solution to fix this problem please

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.automation.driver.StepGlobalUtils
    at com.automation.steps.StepDefinition.<clinit>(StepDefinition.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:223)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:211)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:201)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.automation.steps.StepDefinition
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:223)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:211)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runAfterHooks(Runtime.java:205)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:46)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Could you please provide the unit test itself.

Comment: Do you have any static fields or static init blocks in StepGlobalUtils ?

Comment: Is this happening in the IDE itself, of by using some kind of build tool e.g ant, maven?

Comment: This is my test @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  features={"D:\\PFE 2018\\SopraHRproject\\src\\test\\resources\\com\\soprahr\\foryou\\automation\\features9\\user_profile\\TESTHELA.feature"},
  glue={"com.soprahr.foryou.automation.steps"}
  )
public class TestForSearchRunner {

}

Answer (score 0):

Can u check at line StepDefinition.java:59 which is causing the error.  Its not able to find the dependency jar at the specified line.

Comment: and in stepGlobalUtils i have  this variable                                      private static WebDriver webDriver = new SharedDriver();  as static  and in step definition this                                                         
protected static WebDriver DRIVER = StepGlobalUtils.getWebDriver();                                                               the static methos i kept them between try and catch

Comment: Check if you have all depenedency jars. junit-4.10.jar
selenium-chrome-driver-2.0a4.jar,
selenium-java-2.53.0-srcs.jar,
selenium-java-2.53.0.jar,
selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar, selenium-remote-client-2.0a5.jar

Comment: i added the selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar but it doesn't work also